# SQL Linked Server to MySQL database does not work because of missing or´incorrect schema

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database

I want to establish a linked Server Connection from my Office SQL-Server to a web hosted MySQL-database.

Before that I tried to Setup a Connection to a copy of this MySQL-database on localhost.

I created a linked Server in Management Studio pointing to my MySQL-database
it Looks like this:

Testing the **Connection** was OK, I can see all databases in MySQL.

But when I do a `SELECT` on one of the tables in a certain database I get an **error 7312**.

When I generate a select script by SSMS it Comes up with

`Select * from [MYSQL_local_ASV].[asvdb]..[descriptions]`

not showing any Schema (..) althoug I can connect to the Server.

If I check the table's Schema in MySQL Workbench it Shows the Schema name 'asvdb'. For me it Looks like there is a Schema 'asvdb' with a database called 'asvdb'.

I checked also with `[MYSQL_local_ASV].[asvdb].[asvdb].[descriptions].`
Same error.
Maybe someone can explain me whats wrong with this and have some example of how to connect to a table in a linked Server.

So, the Problem is, I assumed that database and Schema in mysql are the same, but what does SQL-Server Need to complete the Connection string properly?

If I cannot establish this local connectin I will never get it to a web hosted MySQL-database, so please help me!
Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 0):

use this format for select query

Execute ('select * from tablename')at LinkedServername